# Is it possible to install a Databricks notebook into a cluster similarly to a library?

Tags: azure, pyspark, shared-libraries, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to be able to have the outputs/functions/definitions of a notebook **available to be used by other notebooks in the same cluster** without always have run the original one over and over...

---

For instance, **i want to avoid**:

**`definitions_file`**`: has multiple commands, functions etc...`

**`notebook_1`**

```
#invoking definitions file
%run ../../0_utilities/definitions_file
```

**`notebook_2`**

```
#invoking definitions file
%run ../../0_utilities/definitions_file
```

.....

Therefore i want that definitions_file is available for all other notebooks running in the same cluster.

I am using azure databricks.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure this can be acheived using notebooks, having spent some time this summer trying something similar. You'll need to create a library via a wheel file. These are installed at the cluster level and would allow for any notebook to access the functionality like any other package.

If you're up to it, check out pycharm and possibly poetry. This probably isn't the answer you want, as it is way more work but it will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thank you @Danten, and how can I create a library via s wheel file?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as "shared notebook" that is implicitly imported. The closest thing you can do is to package your code as a Python library or into Python file inside Repos, but you still will need to write `from my_cool_package import *` in all notebooks.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I build a library or create a python file inside Repos?

Comment: You can create Python file in Repos via UI -> click on Repo and select Create.  Library should be built outside of the Repo, for example, from CI/CD system.